# How to fix android.view.InflateException while adding bottom navigation in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am Developing an RSS feed app and after successfully adding tabs, splash screen, and navigation drawer.
I want to add bottom navigation and after designing layout I include it to my app.

But after running project the following error appears:

```
       --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.yasht.cricketapp, PID: 3287
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yasht.cricketapp/com.example.yasht.cricketapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.yasht.cricketapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x0
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:228)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:687)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4202)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:579)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:87)
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:118)
        at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.yasht.cricketapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My bottom navigation Layout :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="454dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/Bottomnav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/windowActionBar"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnav_menus">


    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For any information related to my project please comment.

Comment: I think, your layout file is incomplete.

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: @MikeM. Ok i will give you full stack trace

Comment: I'm not sure which example you're following, but `android:background="?attr/windowActionBar"` doesn't really make sense. The `windowActionBar` attribute is for a boolean value. The `background` attribute needs a drawable reference or a color value or reference. Either remove that line, or change the value to something valid.

Comment: @MikeM. I just learn app development and i think best way to learn is to develop apps, but thanks for your help

Comment: Nah, you're fine. I just meant, I've seen that same attribute setting in a few examples online in various places, though I'm not sure where it originated. I was just explaining why it's incorrect, and ultimately causes the Exception.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks now its work